# Вывести всех людей в консоль, вывести средний возраст людей и имя человека с самой большой зарплатой в списке

Tags: массивы

```
var chislo = prompt('Введите ко-во массивов');
var massive = [];

    for (let i=0; i < chislo; i++) {
        massive.push({
            date: (new Date(Math.floor(Math.random() * (d2 - d1) + d1))).toDateString(),
            summ: Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 0 + 1)) + 0,
            name: pn[Math.floor(Math.random() * pn.length)]
        });
    }
    console.table(massive);
```

Не могу понять, как написать циклы в многомерном массиве. Если брать просто массивы через строку, то все ок.

А как именно тут получить - "имя человека с самой большой зарплатой в списке"?
Не могу понять, что вообще делать.

Comment: и проблема то в чем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var personWithMaxSalary = massive.reduce((res, item) => (item.summ > res.summ)? item : res);
console.log(personWithMaxSalary.name, "makes the most money.");
```

> циклы в многомерном массиве

Многомерность тут проявляется не очень сильно.

```
for (var i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
  var item = massive[i];
  console.log(item.name, item.date, item.summ);
}
```